# Eigenvectors and row reduction

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am reducing a row to find the eigenvector. I have the following.
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Can I switch the bottom row with the top row? I am wondering if this will change the value of my eigenvector. For example, I was told that switching rows and columns inverses the sign of the determinant. I am wondering if eigenvectors would have a similar effect as determinants.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1760153/81360).  In general, row operations will alter the eigenvalues of a matrix.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I generally don't like to engage in row reductions, when looking for eigenvalues, because it does have the potential to change them.  And it is not particularly helpful in the next step of finding eigenvectors.  Anyway, you have a singular matrix.  That should make one eigenvalue obvious.

Comment: Is the matrix in your question the original one for which you’re trying to find engenvectors, or one that you reached while trying to compute the null space of $A-\lambda I$?

Answer (score 0):

In fact: the matrix $\pmatrix{0 & 0\\-2 & 2}$ has eigenvalues $0,2$, while $\pmatrix{-2 & 2\\0 & 0}$ has eigenvalues $0,-2$.

It is not *generally* true that switching the rows will flip the sign of some eigenvalue, but that's how it's worked out this time. For instance, 
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$
The matrix on the left has eigenvalues $1,0$, but the matrix on the right has eigenvalues $0,0$.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not at all clear what the matrix that you’ve included in your question is meant to be. Based on “I am reducing a row to find the eigenvector”†, I’m going to guess that this is not the original matrix $A$, but some step along the way of finding eigenvectors of $\lambda$ by computing the null space of $A-\lambda I$. If that’s the case, then feel free to rearrange the rows to your heart’s content. The null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space—the span of its rows. Rearranging rows has no effect whatsoever on this space.

---

† There’s no such thing as “the” eigenvector when you’re working with real matrices. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda$, then any non-zero scalar multiple of $v$ is also an eigenvector of $\lambda$.