# Equivalent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that "elementary transformation of a matrix doesn't change its rank as well as order".

Is this true even while computing eigenvalues of a matrix. That is, is eigenvalues of a matrix and eigenvalues of its equivalent matrix (obtained by sequence of elementary transformation) same?

So that eigenvalues can be easily calculated after reducing a matrix into a triangular (or diagonal) matrix since eigenvalues of a triangular (or diagonal) matrix is nothing but their principal diagonal elements.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1760153/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks got the answer.